# exec, files location problem

Tags: java, file-io, command-line, runtime.exec

In my jar application I do some calculations in exe program. When files and program.exe was in the same dir I used this command:

```
String[] str={"program.exe", "file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
pr = rt.exec(str);
```

and it worked great. But when I moved files to other dir and I try use this command:

```
String[] str={"program.exe", "temp\\file1.txt", "temp\\file2.txt"};
pr = rt.exec(str);
```

program.exe doesn't see files. What is more odd it start to see files when I change its names for anything else that default. file1.txt, file2.txt and temp are created in my jar program before program.exe start.

**edit:**
When problem started I try sth like this: default names file1.txt and file2.txt, I changed to aaa.txt and bbb.txt (in windows), and then:

```
 String[] str={"program.exe", "temp\\aaa.txt", "temp\\bbb.txt"};
```

and it works.

**edit2:**
Now I know that problem is in program.exe. When I use it from command line (not from jar), like this:

```
program.exe temp\file1.txt temp\file2.txt
```

error:

```
FANN Error 1: Unable to open configuration file "temp\file1.txtÉ║@" for reading.
```

fann is artificial neural network library. When I copy files to program.exe dir:

```
program.exe file1.txt file2.txt
```

it works! When I changed files names in temp and do:

```
program.exe temp\file1aaa.txt temp\file2bbb.txt
```

it works also! So it is fann lib bug?

Comment: what is "localization problem" in this.

Comment: What you mean by 'anything else that default...'?

Comment: @sudmong, changed it to 'location', which is what I think was meant.

Comment: Does `program.exe` see files in other dir when run in command line?

Comment: Is temp directory inside the directory, where you run the program?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the ProcessBuilder api (it gives you much more control than `Runtime.exec()`) and I'd also use absolute paths:

```
File directory = new File("/path/tp/program.exe's/parent");

int returnCode = new ProcessBuilder("program.exe", 
    new File(directory, "temp/file1.txt").getAbsolutePath(),
    new File(directory, "temp/file2.txt").getAbsolutePath()
)
.directory(directory).start().waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give complete path of the filename and see. Something like below

```
String[] str = {"program.exe", "D:\\temp\\file1.txt", "D:\\temp\\file2.txt"};
```

If your OS is UNIX based then change it accordingly.

Comment: it doesn't help and my OS is win

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried relative path for finding the location
like

`abc (folder)

 -> code(folder)

  -->Program.Java

 -> temp

  --> file1.txt`

**so 

when u run ur program in Eclipse IDE**
ur relative path will be from program.java file is
`../temp/file1.txt`
And try to use `/` instead of `\` so that it wont take as an escape character.

**when u run from a jar** 
You need to extract the temp folder from jar to outside

`abc (folder)

 -> jar (folder)

  -->Program.jar

 -> temp

  --> file1.txt`

**OR**
Read the jar content from the program as a zip file. Reach your temp folder inside it by code and then read the content as input stream.